# Ionic 3 - Mis cambios no se reflejan cuando compilo

Tags: android, ionic, cordova, ionic3

tengo varios problemas en mi aplicación de ionic.
Cuando modifico las vistas y vuelvo a correr el comando

```
$ sudo ionic cordova run android
```

Se instala el app en mi telefono pero no se reflejan los cambios, algo tan estupido como cambiar una palabra de "Bienvenido" a "Bienvenid000"... sigo viendo en el app "Bienvenido".

Borre la carpeta node_modules, desinstale ionic, instale la ultima version de cordova y de ionic y nada... (El app es una tienda) y cuando la corro en un navegador se ve el precio, cuando la corro en mi android el precio no se ve, sale como "undefined".

Tengo mas de un mes desarrollando esta app y no me habia pasado nada, ayer le instale el codova-plugin-facebook, y me empezó a dar de cualquier tipo. Tienen alguna idea que estoy haciendo mal?

Otra pregunta que tengo es: 
¿Por qué si tengo cordova 8, cuando corro el comando:

```
$ sudo ionic cordova platform add android
```

me sale esto:

```
> cordova platform add android --save
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@~7.0.0
```

"cordova 7"????

Les dejare mi ionic info:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos

Comment: Me paso algo parecido con un proyecto que hice
Me toco instalar npm install promise-polyfill --save-exact
y utilice ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4@1.7.4 --save --variable APP_ID="<myid>" --variable APP_NAME="<myname>" remueve el android, lo adicionas y le haces el build a la aplicacion despues de instalar lo anterior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me paso algo parecido con un proyecto que hice
Me toco instalar:

```
npm install promise-polyfill --save-exact
```

y utilice:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4@1.7.4 --save --variable APP_ID="<myid>" --variable APP_NAME="<myname>"
```

remueve el android, lo adicionas y le haces el build a la aplicacion despues de instalar lo anterior

Comment: No te sabria decir como resolvi el problema, reinicie la mac desinstale todo y volve a instalar, el app pudo levantar de nuevo, pero con un error con un pipe (que lleva un mes funcionando... el pipe de Money) y bueno lo quite y ya pude correr todo perfecto, el plugin de facebook tambien me funciona correctamente! 

El primer comando de promise-polyfill me ayudo a resolver otro detalle, o eso creo, porque simplemente desaparecio! Gracias